# Setting the title of the R console

Tags: r

One quick question to which I could not find answer.

I want to know if it is possible to set the title of the R console to something else (using RGui, on Windows).

The main use I'm thinking of is to show some kind of progress information when running a script which takes a long time to complete.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would `tkProgressBar` in the `tcltk` package do what you're after? It doesn't change the title of the R console, but it does provide a new window whose title is mutable.

Comment: There used to be a function in package `utils` called `setWindowTitle` but it seems that it's gone now...

Comment: There's also a windows-specific `winProgressBar`

Comment: @plannapus, are you sure it's gone away? I don't have a Windows version running but it still seems to be in the source code ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker No you re right, it's not actually gone, just only present in Windows, which I just realized now.

Comment: Thank you, setWindowTitle works just fine (though it changes the title of the whole RGui rather than just the console - even better since it allows me to check progress by simply looking at the minimised window) - I prefer to avoid opening a new Tcl/Tk window just to show a progress bar or a status message... Mostly to avoid cluttering...

Answer (score 6):

In windows you can use the `setWindowTitle` function, the name that you give it will show up in the top of the window or be the label on the icon when it is minimized.

I have the following line in my .Rprofile:

```
utils::setWindowTitle(getwd())
```

So that each instance of R has a label showing which folder/directory it was opened in (I often have several open at a time that I switch between as I work on different projects).  This is nice for starting R by double clicking on the .Rdata file and keeping track of which window is which.

But for indicating the progress of a long running process the progress bars are probably the better approach.  In windows you can use `winProgressBar` or on any platform you can use `txtProgessBar` or `tkProgressBar` (the tcltk package is needed for the 2nd).  The growing bar is a quick visual of the progress and you can also use the label to give a specific iteration, or other information.

Comment: Thank you, setWindowTitle works just great! It'll come in handy in several other use cases...